# Flex Chart, determining chart area (not including

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mx

I am working on a flex application comparing multiple instance of the mx:PlotChart class. I need normalize the various instances of the PlotCharts such that the change in data value per pixel between charts remains constant. To do this, I must find the area of the chart actually used for graphing (and not for the axis labels). The area I am looking for is show (highlighted in fuschia) in the attached screen shot.

Thanks,
-Kevin[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the width and height of the series. Below is an example using a ColumnChart, but of course this will work for another type of chart such as LineChart.

Suppose we have the following data:

```
<mx:XMLListCollection id="dp">
<fx:XMLList>
    <quote date="8/1/2007" open="40.29" close="39.58" />
    <quote date="8/2/2007" open="39.4" close="39.52" />
    <quote date="8/3/2007" open="39.47" close="38.75" />
    <quote date="8/6/2007" open="38.71" close="39.38" />
    <quote date="8/7/2007" open="39.08" close="39.42" />
    <quote date="8/8/2007" open="39.61" close="40.23" />
    <quote date="8/9/2007" open="39.9" close="40.75" />
    <quote date="8/10/2007" open="41.3" close="41.06" />
    <quote date="8/13/2007" open="41" close="40.83" />
    <quote date="8/14/2007" open="41.01" close="40.41" />
    <quote date="8/15/2007" open="40.22" close="40.18" />
    <quote date="8/16/2007" open="39.83" close="39.96" />
    <quote date="8/17/2007" open="40.18" close="40.32" />
    <quote date="8/20/2007" open="40.55" close="40.74" />
    <quote date="8/21/2007" open="40.41" close="40.13" />
    <quote date="8/22/2007" open="40.4" close="40.77" />
    <quote date="8/23/2007" open="40.82" close="40.6" />
    <quote date="8/24/2007" open="40.5" close="40.41" />
    <quote date="8/27/2007" open="40.38" close="40.81" />
</fx:XMLList>
</mx:XMLListCollection>
```

And the following chart:

```
<mx:ColumnChart id="myChart" dataProvider="{dp}" showDataTips="true" width="300">
<mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="@date"/>
</mx:horizontalAxis>
<mx:series>
    <mx:ColumnSeries id="openSeries"
        xField="@date" 
        yField="@open" 
        displayName="Open"/>
</mx:series>
</mx:ColumnChart>
```

Then we can access the width and height of the series:

```
<s:Label text="{openSeries.width}" />
<s:Label text="{openSeries.height}" />
```